# Python pandas, how to only plot a DataFrame that actually have the datapoint and leave the gap out

Tags: python, plot, dataframe, pandas

I have a DataFrame with intraday data indexed with DatetimeIndex

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000',periods=6, freq='1h'))
df2 =pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6,4),index=pd.date_range('1/2/2000',periods=6, freq='1h'))
df3 = df1.append(df2)
```

so as can be seen there is a big gap between within the two days in `df3`

df3.plot()

will plot every single hour from `2000-01-01 00:00:00` to `2000-01-02 05:00:00`, while actually from `2000-01-01 06:00:00` to `2000-01-02 00:00:00` there are actually no datapoint.

How to leave those data point in the plot so that from `2000-01-01 06:00:00` to `2000-01-02 00:00:00` is not plotted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to have been in discussion for some time at Google Groups.

[Pandas Intraday Time Series plots](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/pydata/x46E9Gpac68/oO2w2TiYR4w)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) (hourly) before you plot:

```
df3.resample('H').plot()
```

Note: This ensures you have NaN values between real values which are not plotted (rather than connected). *This means you are storing more data here, which may be an issue.*