# Python Pandas Custom DateTime Index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I'm looking to reindex my data using a custom DateTime index.  I would like the index to be: Sun 5pm-Mon 4PM; Mon 5PM-Tues 4PM;Tues 5PM-Wed 4PM; Wed 5PM-Thurs 4pm; Thurs 5PM-Fri 4PM, in a 1 minute interval.  I have been playing around with the code below but I cant seem to get any data to populate in time_stamps. It seems like my issue might be with when the business day starts and ends and I am not sure how to get around that. Any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
from pandas.tseries.offsets import CustomBusinessDay
import datetime as dt


BDAY_US=CustomBusinessDay(calendar=USFederalHolidayCalendar())
sample_freq= '1min'
dates= pd.date_range(start='2016-07-11',end='2016-07-21', freq=BDAY_US ).date
times = pd.date_range(start='17:00:00', end='16:00:00', freq=sample_freq).time[1:]
time_stamps = [dt.datetime.combine(date, time) for date in dates for time in times]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794030/5276797), you could generate the full range of timestamps, then remove those you are not interested in:

```
time_stamps = pd.date_range('2016-07-11', '2016-07-21', freq='1min')
mask = ~((time_stamps.hour > 16) & (time_stamps.hour < 17))
time_stamps[mask]
```

There are two complications:

**First**, you need to remove Fri 5pm - Sun 4pm

```
weekend_mask = ~(
    ((time_stamps.dayofweek == 4) & (time_stamps.hour >= 17)) |
     (time_stamps.dayofweek == 5) |
    ((time_stamps.dayofweek == 6) & (time_stamps.hour <= 16))
)
mask = mask & weekend_mask
```

**Second**, you want to remove holidays. This part of my linked [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36794030/5276797) may help:

You can include a calendar by adding a condition to the mask:

```
import numpy as np
np.in1d(index.date, calendar)
```

where calendar would be a numpy array of datetime objects.

Comment: Brilliantly simple solution.  I wish I would have found your other answers a while ago. Thank you!

Comment: I had another idea: it would be much simpler to set up the timestamps from 00:00 to 23:00, and then subtract 7 hours from the result. In this case your solution would work too...

Comment: I have been trying to use this in combination with .minute and have not been getting the desired results.  `((time_stamps.hour>7)&(time_stamps.minute>45)&(time_stamps.hour<=8)&(time_stamps.minute<=30))` is not removing the expected time stamps.  Any insight?

Comment: That won't work because `(time_stamps.minute>45)&(time_stamps‌​.minute<=30)` is never true.

Comment: For your purpose you could use `between_time` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179214/selecting-data-between-specific-hours-in-a-pandas-dataframe).